# Reorganizational matching

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, matching-theory, bipartite-graphs

**Motivation.** My friend works in an organization that is re-organizing itself in the following somewhat laborious way: There are $n$ people currently sitting on $n$ jobs in total (everyone has one job). Everyone has to apply for exacty $3$ jobs. They are allowed to apply for the job they are currently on, but they don't have to. This prompts the question: how probable is it that in the end everyone can be matched with one of the jobs they applied for? Let's put this in a formal question.

**Formal version.** Let $k\leq n\in\mathbb{N}$ be positive integers. We write $[n]$ for the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Denote the set of "employees" by $E_n := [n] \times\{1\}$, and the set of "jobs" by $J_n :=[n]\times \{2\}$. So $E_n, J_n$ each have $n$ elements, but they are disjoint.

A *$k$-job selection* is a set $S \subseteq E_n\times J_n$ such that for every $e\in E_n$ there are exactly $k$ elements $j\in J_n$ with $(e,j)\in S$. [Hall's Marriage Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) gives us a criterion that tells us when the resulting bipartite graph $(E_n \cup J_n, S)$ has a [perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching).

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $k(n)$ be the smallest positive integer such that at least for half of the $k(n)$-job selections $S\subseteq E_n\times J_n$ the bipartite graph $(E_n \cup J_n, S)$ has a perfect matching. That is $k(n)$ is the smallest integer such that if everyone applies for $k(n)$ jobs, the probability is at least $50\%$ that everyone can be matched with one of the jobs they applied for.

I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of $k(n)$. More precisely: Is there an explicit formula for $k(n)$? If not, what is the value of $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}k(n)/n$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe there is any company that plays such a game of musical chairs with its employees.

Comment: The company doesn't have thousands of employees.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe there is such a company of any size.

Comment: Do you think the existence of such a company is inconsistent with ${\sf (ZFC)}$?

Comment: I believe it's inconsistent with the culture of mathoverflow to tell lies.

Comment: I believe it is inconsistent with the culture of mathoverflow to accuse another user to tell lies without having solid evidence. (In some countries, it is punishable.)

Comment: That's why I didn't accuse anyone of anything. So: is there such a company, or isn't there?

Comment: There is such an organization. It is not private, but funded by public means, which might explain that they can afford such a cumbersome procedure. Maybe I should have called it an "organization" instead of a "company". Does the word company entail it is private? If so, apologies, and I will change the original post.

Comment: ' the smallest integer such that if everyone applies for k(n)
 jobs, the probability is at least 50%
 that everyone can be matched' => surely k(n) is the probability that if everyone applied for k(n) jobs *at random* (Or with no correlation in preferences and all jobs being 'equally desirable') ....  While the question you are asking might be interesting it has little to do with modeling the situation you describe, since random choices are no choice at all.  If there are m 'awful' jobs there is 0 probability of 'matching' unless k(n) > n-m, so everyone is forced to select an awful job.